# How to perform RPC call system.properties() using py-substrate-interface?

Tags: rpc, python, systemmodule

Is there a way to the RPC call output of `system.properties()` using the py-substrate-interface?  I want to access the token name and decimals as shown below (based on this
[link](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fstatemine-rpc.polkadot.io#/rpc))

```
{
  ss58Format: 2
  tokenDecimals: [
    12
  ]
  tokenSymbol: [
    KSM
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python interface provides convenience functions for this:

```py
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface

client = SubstrateInterface(
    url="wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io/",
    ss58_format=2,
    type_registry_preset='kusama'
)

# Prints: {'ss58Format': 2, 'tokenDecimals': 12, 'tokenSymbol': 'KSM'}
print(client.properties)
```

If there is a method missing, you can manually use `client.rpc_request("system_properties", []).get('result')` instead.

Comment: Thanks Oliver! Very grateful for your answer.  It would be great to get that second method added to the docs (unless it is already there and I missed it).

Comment: It is documented [here](https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-interface/#substrateinterface.SubstrateInterface.rpc_request).